# Random fan activation

Tags: dell, 15.10, fan, fancontrol

Good morning,

I have a home server currently running Ubuntu 15.10. Since the last week I'm experiencing random fan activation, the fan simply goes on for a second and then goes back to basal level for another 10-15 seconds. The cycle never ends. I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu last week. My server is a DELL Inspiron 580. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong. Your computer is noticing that it is warmer than it wants to be, and firing up the fan to cool off. How long has it been since you have cleaned the computer (physical cleaning of fans, heat sinks, general dust removal). A local computer shop could do this for money. What sort of environment does it run in? Can you improve external ventilation?

Is there a system activity pulse (more computing -> more heat) with the same frequency?

Comment: Nope, it can't be an environmental issue since it was running perfectly until the upgrade. I also noticed that until ubuntu is loaded (aka, while I stay in the BIOS) the fan does not overspeed: the only thing I can think of is an upgrade driver or software that killed my system.